# Ubuntu 18.04 Touchpad No Longer Working

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

I've upgraded my Toshiba Satellite C55-B5356 to Ubuntu 18.04 a while ago and have always had trouble with the touchpad. I usually use a usb mouse though so up until now I have never had a need to fix this issue. Recently however I've decided to start backing up my hard drive and purchased a usb tool to attach another drive to copy my files over. Unfortunately I only have one working usb port due to the others being damaged so I'm in a position where I now need the touchpad to work. I have tried a couple things like installing the xserver-xorg-synaptics package however before I go messing things up further I would like to consult others.

My current situation is:

- The touchpad does not respond to any input in ubuntu. Though it does work when in BIOS
- Viewing settings does show the touchpad section and the selector switch is set to on
- the output of `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` is:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
B: PROP=9
B: EV=b
B: KEY=6420 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800011000003
```

- Also the output of `xinput --list` is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech M315/235/317                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Based on what I've read it seems my issue is with drivers since it appears the touchpad is recognized though I've never dealt with that before so I'm not sure how to proceed. What could be causing my touchpad to not function?

Edit:
This is the contents of `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf`:

```
# Example xorg.conf.d snippet that assigns the touchpad driver
# to all touchpads. See xorg.conf.d(5) for more information on
# InputClass.
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE, your distribution will likely overwrite
# it when updating. Copy (and rename) this file into
# /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d first.
# Additional options may be added in the form of
#   Option "OptionName" "value"
#
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
# This option is recommend on all Linux systems using evdev, but cannot be
# enabled by default. See the following link for details:
# http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-ignore-configuration-errors.html
      MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad ignore duplicates"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchOS "Linux"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/mouse*"
        Option "Ignore" "on"
EndSection

# This option enables the bottom right corner to be a right button on clickpads
# and the right and middle top areas to be right / middle buttons on clickpads
# with a top button area.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Default clickpad buttons"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
        Option "SecondarySoftButtonAreas" "58% 0 0 15% 42% 58% 0 15%"
EndSection

# This option disables software buttons on Apple touchpads.
# This option is only interpreted by clickpads.
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Disable clickpad buttons on Apple touchpads"
        MatchProduct "Apple|bcm5974"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "SoftButtonAreas" "0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` is installed, else install it
2. Create a text file name `70-synaptics.conf` at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` or at `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`
3. Below is the direct copy from my old Xubuntu config:

> Section "InputClass"

Identifier "Touchpad" # required

MatchIsTouchpad "yes" # required

Driver "synaptics" # required

Option "MinSpeed" "0.2"

Option "MaxSpeed" "0.5"

Option "AccelFactor" "0075"

Option "TapButton1" "1"

Option "TapButton2" "2" # multitouch

Option "TapButton3" "3" # multitouch

Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "1" # multitouch

Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1" # multitouch

Option "VertEdgeScroll" "1"

Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "1"

Option "CoastingSpeed" "8"

Option "CornerCoasting" "1"

Option "CircularScrolling" "1"

Option "CircScrollTrigger" "7"

Option "EdgeMotionUseAlways" "1"

Option "LBCornerButton" "8" # browser "back" btn

Option "RBCornerButton" "9" # browser "forward" btn

EndSection

4. Reboot

Comment: Sorry for the delay something came up and I wasn't home yesterday. I checked `sudo apt list --installed | grep xf86-input-synaptics` and nothing was returned so I assume it is not installed. I ran `apt update` and tried installing it it failed. Googling found [this](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/xf86-input-synaptics) page on which I followed the link to download. I decompressed the file and am left with a folder /usr/. Should just copy it into my /usr/ folder or is there a different way? From what I've read there should be a configure file or readme but I dont see one.

Comment: My apology, the package name changed, please see the updated name on the main solution, I provided.

Comment: No outside packages please, just follow exactly as I mentioned. I had this issue beforehand with Xubuntu on Acer netbook, it got solved that way.

Comment: I ran `sudo apt list --installed | grep xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and it returned `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/bionic,now 1.9.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]`. I added the section in your screenshot to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf and restarted but it dropped me into what I believe is a virtual terminal (no desktop just a black screen with a terminal prompt). I used vi to undo the edits and restarted and the desktop comes up again, though the problem still remains. I edited my original question with the contents of that file (without the edit) in case it's relevant.

Comment: Move the 70-synaptics.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/.  If xorg.conf.d directory not present, please create one. Then reboot.

Comment: Moving it gave the same output as the original edit. Black screen when restarting with a terminal prompt. I had to remove the edit with vi to get it to show the desktop again.

Comment: Please check the updated solution above, copied directly from the file I used

Comment: Sorry same outcome. Black screen on startup. I did get some help from a friend in backing up my drive which was my main goal though so it isn't a pressing concern anymore to get this working. Thank you for all of your help though I do appreciate it.